# cshtml c# not listening to assigned id for some reason?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, razor

So I have a basic CRUD I am working on, and Im trying to get Jquery validation working on it. I have it almost all set up except I need to give my form an id. I am using cshtml in visual studio and try to assign the id to the form using the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( new { id = "daftform" })) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
<legend>News</legend>
```

However the generated html looks like this:

```
<form action="/News/Create/daftform" method="post">    <fieldset>
    <legend>News</legend>
```

I am pretty sure this is how to assign an id to an element as I use this method to assign classes in a similar way. Can anyone tell me where im going wrong?

I just want it to assign 'daftform' as an id not as an action.

Sorry if its a simple answer, fairly new to c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)  overload

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    FormMethod method,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

So your code can be changed to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","News",FormMethod.Post, new { id = "daftform" }))
{
  //form elements
}
```

This will create a `form` tag with `Id` property set to `"daftform"`

Answer (score 0):

@using (Html.BeginForm(,"actionname","controllername",formmethod.post/get, new {id = "yourId"})

is the way to go